# Hive tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1") not working with select distinct

Tags: hive

We have a little problem with our `tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1")`.
If we do a basic select like `select * from tableabc` we do not get back this header. But once we do a `select distinct columnname from tableabc` we get the header back!

Of course we do not want this for obvious reasons.

Did somebody else also have this issue? If so did you find a fix for this?

Thx in advance

-----Update 20/06/2018-----

Hive2 version: 2.1

running on: Azure HDInsight hive interactive query cluster

This is a very small data set already, 48 records (with header included)

Create Statement:

```
-----------------------------------
--sap_0bill_typea--
-----------------------------------
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ext.test_type_in
  (
    test_type      string
    )
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\073'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 'adl://{adlslocation}data/data2/test'
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1")
```

Select statement:

```
select * from test_type_in;
```

Distinct statement

```
select distinct test_type from test_type_in ORDER BY test_type;
```

I cannot show the exact statement because of NDA so i changed those values to test.

Comment: did you check the files do not contain multiple header rows?

Comment: Yep we checked that and there is only one row. Also else this would show up in the select * and it did not.

Comment: can you  reproduce this with a small sample file ? also Hive version would be useful. table creation statement, select query and distinct query

Comment: updated my question with your answers

Comment: thanks! the only thing that I do not see is the sample data

Comment: I cannot deliver any sample data because we are under heavy NDA, but it is just a string between 3-15 characters